# BOUML command line reverse-engineer

Tags: command-line, uml, command-line-arguments

I would like to ask you whether there exists a way to automate reverse-engineering of a certain project in BOUML. It is tedious to do the same thing for every project. May be there is a way to do this automatically? Like a command line argument? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can launch automatically a reverse *plug-out* like any other *plug-out* through a command line, refer to the documentation http://bouml.free.fr/doc/index_plugout.html looking at *To start a plug-out when Bouml is launch*. Best regards and happy modeling.

Comment: Thanks for registering just to answer :) Also your product is really _really_ useful (if you really are Bruno Pagès, of course). Many thanks anyway :)